# Can't resubmit Open Graph Action to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, submission

I submitted a watch action for Open Graph approval. It was rejected and the status shows:

Watch - Movie, TV Show, TV Episode - Changes Needed · Get Code

How do I resubmit: "Changes Needed" is not a clickable link and all of the changes were on "my" web site... and I don't see any kind of submit button anywhere for this action.

Please make changes below and resubmit for review.
1.) If your app publishes built-in watch actions for video, you must give users clear, ongoing, and in-context messaging (such as on the page where the user watches the video) that their watch actions will be published on Facebook. 2.) If you plan on using an in-line control, your app needs to explain to users how the control works, including the fact that the app will publish watches to the user's timeline when sharing is enabled. 3.) You must provide users with the ability to remove any video stories you publish to Facebook, and include this option on the same page where you host the video content. 4.) Watch actions may only be published only after the user has watched at least 10 seconds of the video content. Once you have made the appropriate changes please re–submit. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to do this was to delete the action and re-create the action from scratch... and then submit it.

Comment: How did you fulfilled the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to delete you actions, just go to your action settings and click the "Save Changes" button again. Then you will be able to resubmit your action again.